# Implementing Keras custom loss function with greater than operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am creating a custom loss function with Keras and TF as the backend. The loss function computes the proportion of elements with errors that are greater than some threshold.

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, thresh=1e-6):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    div_result = Lambda(
        lambda x: x[0] / x[1])(
        [y_true_f - y_pred_f, y_true_f])
    greater = K.greater(div_result, thresh)
    return K.sum(K.cast(greater, 'float32'))
```

Not surprisingly, I run into the error "An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval." I think this is because the K.greater operation is not differentiable.

Is there any way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `K.max` instead?

Comment: @ChompakornCChaichot I want the tensor Greater to have ones at the elements where div_result is greater than thresh and zeros elsewhere. Wouldn't K.max just give either div_result or thresh at each element, whichever is larger?

Comment: I just read your loss function in details, I'm not sure why you implement your loss function this way. Supposed that you want to minimize loss (error of y_pred and y_true), your loss function is `K.greater((y_true-y_pred)/y_true, thresh)`. To transform this into an equation, its $argmax max((y_true-y_pred)/y_true, thresh)$. Both case doesn't make any sense. If you were to minimize $(y_true-y_pred)/y_true$, y_true is constant w.r.t. model parameter and you ends up minimizing $y_true-y_pred$ instead. Why don't you minimize L1 loss instead?